# What's the difference between encode and convert in Notepad++?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, notepad++

The Encoding menu has submenus of `Encode in utf-8` and `Convert to utf-8` in Notepad++. What's the difference between them?

Comment: Encode in UTF-8 reads the bytes as if they were encoded in UTF-8, which could change the chars you see. Convert to UTF-8 reads the bytes and tries to convert the bytes to be valid UTF-8 encoded bytes, which should keep the chars you see the same.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Short version:**

- `Encode in` keeps the bytes, and modifies the characters.
- `Convert to` keeps the characters, and modifies the bytes.

---

**Encode**

`Encode in ...` specifies how bytes are interpreted. Example:

Create new file UTF-8 (no BOM), and insert character `ä`. File will contain bytes `C3 A4`. If you select `Encode in ANSI`, you will see 2 different characters, but underlying bytes are still the same `C3 A4`.

Note that sometimes byte sequence is invalid in selected encoding, and Notepad++ might have to change it.

You usually use `Encode in ...` if Notepad++ guesses the file encoding incorrectly.

**Convert**

`Convert to ...` tries to keep the text content same, but changes the underlying bytes. Example:

Create new file UTF-8 (no BOM), and insert character `ä`. Select `Convert to ANSI`, and character will remain the same `ä`, but bytes have changed to `E4`. (If character set was `ISO 8859-1`.)

You usually use conversion if you want to change the file encoding, for example, to make file compatible with some other program.

Comment: I find the Notepad++ sometimes does convert the bytes even if you just change the encoding... Like you open a UTF-8 file, and then you choose "Encode in UCS-2 LE BOM", you will find the character does not change, and the icon left to the file name has become red, meaning the file has been changed...

Comment: @JingHe Yes, that is true. This is especially noticeable with conversions between different Unicode encodings. Some encodings require Byte Order Mark, which is not convertible as is between encodings. As a result, in these cases Encode works pretty much like Convert.